Are business sales tax calculated before or after the bank and other fees in Quebec and Canada?
I am preparing to file sales tax for a new business I have set up in Quebec, Canada. Currently it's only operating in the province of Quebec.
Let's say I charge a customer $100 and Quebec and Canada sales tax is 14.975% so that would be $114.975. Now my customers pay with a credit card and Stripe charges 2.9% + $0.30. I also have other fixed and variable costs to be paid just like Stripe. Let's say x, y and z. Now does the sales tax is calculated on $100 or $100 minus all the fees?

Isn't it you who pays the credit card and Stripe charges?

@DJClayworth yes the business does but my question if sales tax is calculated with the bank fees or without?

My understanding is that the sales tax is based on whatever you charge the customer.

Is this about preparing the sales tax return to figure out the net sales tax your business should remit to the government after collecting on sales? Unfortunately that's a business accounting question and not a personal finance question; i.e. off-topic.

Sales taxes are based on whatever you sell the product for:

The most common consumption taxes for Québec residents are:

the goods and services tax (GST), which is calculated at a rate of 5% on the selling price; and
the Québec sales tax (QST), which is calculated at a rate of 9.975% on the selling price excluding the GST.


Emphasis mine.
